# Storing reference (hash?) to the node for conditional manipulation

Tags: performance, xslt, conditional-statements

Given this pseudo-code:

```
   <xsl:variable name="check0">
       <xsl:value-of select="($externalFile//i[@attibute = $variable]/../@start < $genDate) and
                             ($externalFile//i[@attibute = $variable]/../@stop  > $genDate)"/>
    </xsl:variable>


   <xsl:variable name="check1">
       <xsl:value-of select="($externalFile//i[@attibute = $variable]/../@start < $genDate) and
                             ($externalFile//i[@attibute = $variable]/../@stop  > $genDate)"/> 
   </xsl:variable>
```

Above code checks if some variable is in date range of attributes taken from external .xml file

---

**Is there a way to store the reference to the file so that this:**

`$externalFile//i[@attibute = $variable]` **look-up doesn't happen 4 times?**

Something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="check3">
    <xsl:value-of select="($externalFile//i[@attibute = $variable]/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:if $check3/../@start > someValue />
<xsl:if $check3/../@stop  < someValue />

<xsl:variable name="outcome">
    <xsl:value-of select="$check3/../@price"/> // <-- retrive some data 
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "Yes". You simply need to change your `check3` variable to this:

```
<xsl:variable name="check3" select="$externalFile//i[@attibute = $variable]" />
```

This way you are referencign the `i` node in the external file directly, rather than getting the text value of it (which is what `xsl:value-of` will do)

Comment: Thank you for fast reply, I'll check it out asap.

Comment: is there a possibility to call check's parent attribute? e.g. `check/../@attr `

Comment: Yes, you will be still able to access any node in the external document still, if you know the relative path. The expression `$check3/../@attr` is perfectly valid.